# disable SpaceVim layers

Tags: spacevim

SpaceVim is very slow for me on large files, and in order to track down what's causing it, I'd like to disable an entire layer (for example, the autocomplete layer)... how would I go about doing this?

Comment: You should ask that to the authors/maintainers via the [issue tracker](https://github.com/SpaceVim/SpaceVim/issues) you'll have a better chance to get an answer from someone who knows well how the plugin works.

Answer (score 2):

In SpaceVim, all layers is a list in `g:spacevim_plugin_groups`. you can remove item in it. but it is not better way to remove layers. we will Update document about layer config. please check out the PRs in spacevim repo.

Thanks!